# IsNullOrEmpty not working in C#, but "null"works

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

```
priavate void getfoo( ){
OracleDataReader myDataReader;
OracleRefCursor myCursor = (OracleRefCursor)cmd.Parameters["omyDATA"].Value;
myDataReader = myCursor.GetDataReader();
fillmytable(myDataReader);
}

private void fillmytable(OracleDataReader mydataReader) {    
StringBuilder myStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();                   
if( mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n) == "null")
{
    mystringbuilder.Append("");
}
else
{
    mystringbuilder.Append(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n).ToString();
}
```

}
Output: ***_***

but if I want to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` like,

```
if(String.IsNullorEmpty(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n).ToString())
{
    mystringbuilder.Append("");
} 
else
{
    mystringbuilder.Append(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n).ToString();
}
```

Output: null

so the question is "null" string test works, but IsNullorEmpty does not work
I need to test GetOracleValue is null or not if it is null, then replace it by empty space.

Comment: If the first snippet works, then your string must be `"null"`, and of course not `null` nor `DBNull.Value`. I'm not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Well, you're missing one )
if(String.IsNullorEmpty(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n)))

Comment: also you're not checking for null when it works.. you're checking the text value "null"

Comment: @RandyJames Does this answers the question?

Comment: I don't think `if(String.IsNullorEmpty(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n))` line will compile. `GetOracleValue` method returns object whereas `IsNullorEmpty` requires `string`. How does this compiles for you?

Comment: I don't want to test oracle object like string, I want to test null on oracle object, I can't find any way to test for null on oracle object  so I decided to convert it to string then check for null, again it does not work. and yeah,     if(String.IsNullorEmpty(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n).ToString()) I forgot to type but it is there

Answer (score 3):

In your first example you are checking for a string that has a value of null. In your second example you are checking if the value is actually null.  What a database returns when record is null is System.DBNull

The reason why the first snippet works is because it is checking if it has a value of "null" which it never does so it goes to the else statement.

have a look at this website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx

EDIT:

I think this should work.

```
if( mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n) != DBNull.Value)
{
    mystringbuilder.Append(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n).ToString();
}
else
{
    mystringbuilder.Append("");
}
```

Comment: no,no, in first snippet it goes to  mystringbuilder.Append(""); which is correct, but in second, it goes to mystringbuilder.Append(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n).ToString(); it returns null, which is incorrect. ( so I edited my question, it created confusion  because I forgot to put .ToString() )

Comment: DBNull actually returns a value in a string.  go to your console and print out System.DBNull.Value and see what comes up, this is why your empty or null will not work.  You are checking if the string is null or the string is empty with your String.IsNullOrEmpty and it will never be because DBNull.Value has an actual value that can be converted to string.  In short, you can't do that check with empty or null.

Comment: what are the options for me? because hard coded "null" I dont like

Comment: I tried that, DBNull.Value.Equals(mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n)) doesnt work, it still goes to else, and returns null

Comment: can you please post the whole method?

Comment: Edit your question, and include the whole block of code that connects you to the database and reads the results.  I don't have enough information to help you as it is.

Comment: I edited again and added all the methods involved.

Comment: I edited my answer, I need to go; I will check if this has worked for you in couple hours, unless somebody else beats me to it.  Good luck.

Comment: I think the issue I'm experiencing is related to the odp.net for 64 bit server, this code likely would work on 32 bit server. We have had DBNull issues with other code converting to 64 bit. Other code is converted to INullable but don't know that it can be used with OracleDataReader.GetOracleValue. This is how we have converted other code.                                                              (!((INullable)cmd.Parameters["pEMAILTO"].Value).IsNull)

Comment: I have to admit that I am confused with exactly what is not working, the code snippet I gave you basically checks if the value is not null and then executes the print statement, if it is null then it appends an empty string.  Did you check the values that you are getting back?  Are you 100% positive that a correct value is coming back from your database?  What value is mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n).ToString() returning?

Comment: It is returning "null", instead of empty space. The issue is because of  Oracle client for 64 bit handling     mydataReader.GetOracleValue(n).ToString() diffrently than 32 bit. So according to you your given snippet, it compares null to "null" which is false, so it returned "null".